# Best way to use UserDefaults with ObservableObject in Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to save user basic's data in UserDefaults.

**My goal** is to be able to consume data from UserDefaults **and** to update them each time the user do some changes.

I'm using an ObservableObject class to set and get these data

```
class SessionData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedInUser: User = User(first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "")
    static let shared = SessionData()

    func setLoggedInUser (user: User) {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(user) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "User")
            self.loggedInUser = currentUser
        }
    }
```

and also

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sessionData: SessionData = SessionData.shared
    var body: some View {
      VStack{
        Text(self.sessionData.loggedInUser.first_name)
      }
    }
}
```

This way the changes are updated. But if I leave the app I will lose the data.

**Solution 2:**
I also tried to rely on reading the data from UserDefault like this

```
class SessionData : ObservableObject {
    func getLoggedInUser() -> User? {
        if let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "User") as? Data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let loadedUser = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: currentUser) {
                return loadedUser
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Problem**: I don't get the updates once a user change something :/

I don't find a nice solution to use both UserDefaults and ObservableObject

Comment: You don't appear to have any code to read the data from `UserDefaults`

Comment: that's the second problem. if I rely on reading the data from UserDefaults I m not able to update them.

Comment: Why can you not do both? Can you show the code that you've tried for reading that you believe is preventing you from updating the data?

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: It sounds like you basically want `@AppStorage`, but to be used with custom types that you're using JSON encoding for. You could make a new property wrapper around `@AppStorage`, or you could start from scratch with the principals detailed here: https://xavierlowmiller.github.io/blog/2020/09/04/iOS-13-AppStorage

Comment: Or, look here: https://lostmoa.com/blog/SaveCustomCodableTypesInAppStorageOrSceneStorage/

Answer (score 1):

in "getLoggedInUser()" you are not updating the published var "loggedInUser".
Try this to do the update whenever you use the function:

```
func getLoggedInUser() -> User? {
    if let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "User") as? Data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let loadedUser = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: currentUser) {
            loggedInUser = loadedUser  // <--- here
            return loadedUser
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

or just simply this:

```
func getLoggedInUser2() {
    if let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "User") as? Data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let loadedUser = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: currentUser) {
            loggedInUser = loadedUser  // <--- here
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do this to automatically save your User when it changes (instead of using setLoggedInUser):

```
@Published var loggedInUser: User = User(first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "") {
    didSet {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(loggedInUser) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "User")
        }
    }
}
```

and use this as init(), so you get back what you saved when you leave the app:

```
init() {
    getLoggedInUser2()
}
```